# PHP 7 intdiv() vx floor or custom type cast

Tags: php, php-7.1

I am looking PHP 7 new Additions in order to improve my skills, i want to know what exactly the difference between the `intdiv()` vs `floor()` or custom `type cast`

**for example**

```
echo (int) (8/3); // 2
echo floor((8/3)); // 2
echo intdiv((8/3)); // 2
```

what exactly the reason for this function to add in newer version of PHP.

Comment: https://why-cant-we-have-nice-things.mwl.be/requests/intdiv

Comment: `intdiv` essentially boils down to this: `($a - $a % $b) / $b;`, which is not the same as `floor()`.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

In general all these three you mentioned works similar as of your example but `intdiv()` will give you more accurate result while working extremely large set of numbers

**here is example you can see.**

```
echo PHP_INT_MAX; // 9223372036854775807

echo (int)(PHP_INT_MAX/2); // 4611686018427387904
// here you can look the ending number

echo floor(PHP_INT_MAX/2); // 4.6116860184274E+18
// here you can see floor will return scientific notation for larger numbers

echo intdiv(PHP_INT_MAX,2); // 4611686018427387903
// you can compare the result return by (int) cast
```

**`intdiv()`** always give you positive number or in other word **`intdiv()`** let you know how many times you can divide evenly

Another example developer always use `Modulus` Operator in order to get remainder but `intdiv()` will always return you positive numbers and let you know how many times you can divide evenly.

```
echo (5 % 2) // 1
echo intdiv(5, 2) // 2
```

Hope this good enough to understand the difference among all 3 of them..

Comment: There is a difference: `intdiv(-10, 3)` == `-3` while `floor(-10/3)` == `-4`.

Comment: *intdiv() always give you positive number* erm, no it doesn't. See above. `intdiv(-10, 3)` == `-3`.

Comment: I don't see any edits? At the moment, this answer is incorrect.

Comment: well `intdiv()` return how many time i can divide evenly good examples thank you

Answer (score 0):

`(int)` casts the value to `int` whereas `floor()` keeps a `float` as a `float`. You used positive numbers in your example, but the difference is in negative numbers.
`intdiv`was designed to keep `int` after division of 2 `int`s.

```
echo (int) (-8/3); // -2
echo floor(-8/3); // -3
echo intdiv(-8,3); //-2
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a different in how they behave in terms of rounding.
`divint()` is more intelligent, it always knows if it supposes to round up or down.

### floor()

With `floor()`, you will always round the value lover so:

`3.33333` becomes `3` 
`-3.33333` becomes `-4`

Which is often not what you intend.

### divint()

`divint` will round to the closest number:

`3.33333` becomes `3` 
`-3.33333` becomes `-3`

### Casting to (int)

Casting float/double to a `int` will perform similary like divint. So you can use:

`(int)(10/3)` returns `3` 
`(int)(-10/3)` returns `-3`